# How to set the Controller Id for the test code?

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test

I have the following class

```
public with sharing class templicenseemail {
    private ApexPages.standardController standardController;

    public Trainee__c trainee { get; set; }
    public templicenseemail(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.standardController = standardController;
    }
    public PageReference doSomething() {
        trainee  = [SELECT Email__c,First_Name__c,Institution__c,Last_Name__c FROM Trainee__c 
                WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

        String whatIs = trainee.Volume_Serial_Number__c;
        integer strlen = whatIs.length();

        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, trainee.Email__c  ));
        return null;
    }   
}
```

With the following test code:

```
@isTest(seealldata=false)
private class Send_noti_emailsTestClass5 {
    static testMethod void validateSend_noti_emails5() {
        Trainee__c o = new Trainee__c(Email__c='email', First_Name__c ='Name',Institution__c= 'InstName',Last_Name__c ='Name' , Id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'));
        insert o;
        Trainee__c myTestTrainee = [SELECT Id From Trainee__c LIMIT 1];

        PageReference myVfPage = Page.sendinstantemail;
        Test.setCurrentPage(myVfPage);
        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(myTestTrainee);
        templicenseemail testController = new templicenseemail(sc);

        testController.trainee= o;

        testController.doSomething();
    }
}
```

I get an error 'system.queryexception list has no rows for assignment to sobject' in the class at line:

```
trainee  = [SELECT Email__c,First_Name__c,Institution__c,Last_Name__c FROM Trainee__c 
                WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
```

This is because i am not setting the Id correctly in the test code,

Can someone tell me whats wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of the way you are getting the ID, through the page parameters, you need to set the page parameters in the test code

Something like this will work

```
system.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('Id', myTestTrainee.Id);
```

I might suggest just using the getRecord() in your constructor, instead of taking it from the page parameters, unless you are using some sort of URL hacking.

```
public templicenseemail(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
     this.standardController = standardController;
     this.trainee = (Trainee__c)standardController.getRecord();
}
```

Comment: So your solution works, but i have another [i am not showing here] class i call from the templicenseemail class, and it does not see the email address i am setting with o, could you tell me why?

Comment: In other words, im sending the email to the other class, but the email doesnt seem to work, because when i try to query records based on that email, i also get "system.queryexception list has no rows for assignment to sobject' error.

Comment: I would be happy to help, but I would suggest adding another question to increase visibility on the new issue

Answer (score 2):

In your test code, just add the ID to the page parameters

```
Test.setCurrentPage(myVfPage);   
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', myTestTrainee.Id);
```

Comment: you have to put myTestTrainee.Id as sfdc_ninja states, or you will get an error.

Comment: You're right. Didn't pay close enough attention to what I was typing.